# PHP LDAP showing blank screen

Tags: php, ldap, single-sign-on, var

Whats wrong with the code below? I have changed the domain and server name etc. for privacy reasons.

The code just shows a blank page when it should show at the very least the VAR dumps?

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['AUTH_PASSWORD'])){

    $adServer = "ldap://OURSERVER";

    $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
    $username = $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
    $password = $_SERVER['AUTH_PASSWORD'];
    $shortname = explode('\\', $_SERVER['AUTH_USER']));

    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $username, $password);


    if ($bind) {
        $filter="(sAMAccountName=$shortname)";
        $result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=OURDOMAIN,dc=local",$filter);
        ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
        {
            if($info['count'] > 1)
                break;
            echo "<p>You are accessing <strong> ". $info[$i]["sn"][0] .", " . $info[$i]["givenname"][0] ."</strong><br /> (" . $info[$i]["samaccountname"][0] .")</p>\n";
            echo '<pre>';
            //var_dump($info);
            var_dump($_SERVER);
            echo '</pre>';
            $userDn = $info[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]; 
        }
        @ldap_close($ldap);
    } else {
        $msg = "Invalid credentials. For more information please contact PHONENUMBER.";
        echo $msg;
    }

}else{
?>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Username: </label><input id="username" type="text" name="username" /> 
        <label for="password">Password: </label><input id="password" type="password" name="password" />        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've added that and it shows no errors, just the blank screen again.

Comment: Does your code enter the if condition?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Add an echo right after `if($bind) {` Do you get that echo?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Nope, I do not.

Comment: Then you bind is failing. You're currently suppressing the error message (it may be in your error logs) with the `@` on `@ldap_bind`. Remove that, rerun the code.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I commented out this line:  $shortname = explode('\\', $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'])); and it now shows the echo but doesn't show anything below the echo?

Comment: Did you remove the `@`?

Comment: @jayblanchard Yes I have removed the @ from the ldap_bind

Comment: Did you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out the fix:

Changes to line 10 as follows: $shortname = explode('\', $_SERVER['AUTH_USER']);

and line 19:         $filter="(sAMAccountName=$shortname[1])";